# Does dynamic_link_first_open event also trigger first_open?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links

Basicly I wanted to count the following firebase events:

- app_open
- first_open
- dynamic_link_app_open
- dynamic_link_first_open

I thought, that usually only one of this events is triggered when a user opens the app, depending on if he/she comes through a dynamic link or not and if he/she opens the app for the first time or not.
But now I detected, that I have some first_open and dynamic_link_first_open events with the same app_instance_id with only 2-10 seconds difference in their timestamp. Does that mean, that if a user open the app for the first time through a dynamic link both dynamic_link_first_open **and** first_open events are triggered? And what about dynamic_link_app_open and app_open?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

You're correct. If the user opens the app for the first time using dynamic link, it will log both first_open event and the dynamic_link_first_open event.

The [dynamic_link_app_open](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en) event will be logged when the user re-opens the app via a Firebase Dynamic Link.

On the other hand, the [app_open](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#APP_OPEN) is one of the Google Analytics for Firebase (GA4F) suggested events and can be used (or logged) when an app is moved to foreground state. This will help you to understand how often users leave and return during the course of a session. Although Sessions are automatically reported, this event can provide further clarification around the continuous engagement of app-users.

Comment: Alright, so to get all first open events I just have to count the first_opens, because they include the dynamic_link_first_open.
But looking at the app_open events: the app open events are not automatically triggered when a dynamic_link_app_open event is triggered.
So for counting all open events I have to sum up first_open, app_open and dynamic_link_app_open?

Comment: has anyone else had trouble with "dynamic_link_app_open" not recording the dynamic_link_link_id on iOS like it does for Android?

Comment: @Dave, we have exactly the same problem - the dynamic_link_link_id is collected for events originating from Android, but not iOS. Have you found the root cause for this and any workarounds? Thanks

Comment: If I remember correctly the only thing we needed to do was update the firebase SDK and then it fixed it. I think there was a resolved bug.  We're currently on Swift 5 so I don't think there were any limitations on the build process to include the new package